# Showing scans the barcode on the data-role = page, using jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I tried to make a barcode scanner with cordova , and has been running well , but after I use jquery mobile scan results do not appear on the page ?

this my Html

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>
            <button id="startScan">Start Scan</button>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="results">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Reslut</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div id="results"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
    function init() {
        document.querySelector("#startScan").addEventListener("touchend", startScan, false);
        resultDiv = document.querySelector("#results");
    }

    function startScan() {

        cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
            function (result) {
                var s = "Result: " + result.text + "<br/>" +
                "Format: " + result.format + "<br/>" +
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled;
                resultDiv.innerHTML = s;
            },
            function (error) {
                alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
            }
        );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 divs that have the ID `result`, IDs should be unique. I would change the ID of the div with the `data-role="page"` to `pageResults`.

Also, you have to change to the results page show the results.

**Try this:**

`$("mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#results")` before you set the innerHTML on that result div.

[Pagecontainer change docs](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change)

Comment: thank @utamanna i try but i am click button scan cannot run, can you write example script.